# Ubuntu Server - Postfix Issue

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, authentication, sasl

I have an issue receiving an email into my server here is what shows in the mail.log file:

```
Nov  1 10:50:30 hoskin postfix/smtpd[20806]: warning: SASL: Connect to /var/spool/postfix/private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Nov  1 10:50:30 hoskin postfix/smtpd[20806]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Nov  1 10:50:31 hoskin postfix/master[1676]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtpd pid 20806 exit status 1
Nov  1 10:50:31 hoskin postfix/master[1676]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

Can any help or advise me on what to do?

Comment: Please include your actual configuration in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to Serverfault. Don't let the downvotes discourage you. Good reading here: https://serverfault.com/help/asking

to fix your issue try this:

```
chown postfix:postfix /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
chmod 666 /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
```

Then in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf (or /usr/local/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf) modify like this -

```
      unix_listener auth-userdb {
        mode = 0666
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
      }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
  }
```

Then restart dovecot:

```
/etc/init.d/dovecot restart
```

Comment: Hi Hayden, I tried what you suggested above and this what I got when I tried to start Dovecot again. `Error: service(stats): Socket already exists: /var/run/dovecot/stats
Error: service(ssl-params): Socket already exists: /var/run/dovecot/ssl-params` there is more error but it exceed the character limit